# Sudoku generation: it goes in loop

Tags: c++, algorithm, sudoku

I'm trying to wiriting a sudoku generator algorithm, this is my c++ code:

```
void generateSudoku(num sudoku[][N])
{   int i,j,k;
    int vett[N],n,old;
    //clean the sudoku matrix filling it with -1
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        for(j=0;j<N;j++)
            sudoku[i][j].val=-1;
    //generate the sudoku
    for(i=0;i<N;){
        for(j=0;j<N;){
            k=0;
            clean(vett,N);  //fills the vector with -1
            old=sudoku[i][j].val; //saves the actual value
            do{
                if(k<9){
                    do{
                        n=rand()%9+1;
                    }while(find(vett,N,n)); //generate n while it already exists in vett
                    vett[k++]=n;
                    if((!(exists(sudoku,i,j,n))) && (n!=old)){ //if it not exists on row, column and sub-matrix and it's different between the old value, it's OK
                        sudoku[i][j++].val=n;
                        if(j==N) i++;
                        k=10;
                        }
                }
                else{
                    sudoku[i][j].val=-1;  
                    if(j>0) j--;
                    else if(i>0){
                        j=N-1;
                        i--;
                    }
                    k=10;
                }

            }while(k<=9);
        }
    }
}
```

It goes in loop and I know the reason:

```
2 7 6 | 9 1 3 | 4 5 8
4 3 9 | 5 7 2 | * *
```

In this example it continues to generate 6-1 and then 1-6 where there are * and it never finishes. But even if I comprend why it loops, I don't know the best way to correct it. Can someone help me?

Comment: You should store forbidden values, here you can only backtrack one level.

Comment: I thought it, using an array for every value with all forbidden values, but I'm not sure it can work. When I should clean the vector?

Comment: You may clean each time 3 rows are entirely fill in.

Comment: I tried:

`if((!(exists(sudoku,i,j,n))) && (!find(sudoku[i][j].old,N,n))){
   sudoku[i][j++].val=n;
   sudoku[i][j].old[sudoku[i][j].t++]=n;
                        if(j==N) i++;
   k=10;
  }`

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You have to backtrack further. There's no valid entry in the last cell of that second row. I'm not sure a greedy algorithm is going to work as sudoku generator. I'd try with a stack-tree based approach instead.

Answer (score 0):

Following may help (untested) :

```
void restore(std::vector<int>& v) {
    v.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i != 9; ++i) {
        v.push_back(1 + i);
    }
}

void generate(int (&sudoku)[9][9])
{
    std::vector<int> allowedSymbols[9][9];

    bool succeed = true;
    for(int i = 0, j = 0; i != 9; ) {
        if (succeed) {
            restore(allowedSymbols[i][j]);
            succeed = false;
        }
        while (!allowedSymbols[i][j].empty()) {
            int index = rand() % allowedSymbols[i][j].size();

            if (!exists(sudoku, i, j, allowedSymbols[i][j][index])) { //if it not exists on row, column and sub-matrix, it is OK
                succeed = true;
                break;
            }
            allowedSymbols[i][j].erase(allowedSymbols[i][j].begin() + index);
        }
        if (succeed) {
            ++j;
            if (j == 9) {
                j = 0;
                ++i;
            }
        } else {
            // backtrack.
            --j;
            if (j == -1) {
                j = 8;
                --i;
            }
            allowedSymbols[i][j].erase(std::find(allowedSymbols[i][j].begin(),
                                                 allowedSymbols[i][j].end(),
                                                 sudoku[i][j]));
        }
    }
}
```